# How to avoid repeated values for multiple column in postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to fetch data like output table[see output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ASq0.jpg) from database table(brackinfo2)[see brackinfo2 table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjbOk.jpg)

Description:In a postgresql database table(brackinfo2),section column has value 1 multiple(5)times for id 1 to 5.and others columns(branchcode,sub_sec_id,point & question_point) also has same values for multiple(5) times.But without question_point column values,I do not want repeated values of another columns.

So how can i write query for that so that I can show value like output table for database table(brackinfo).

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a report. Reports can suppress duplicate values on output, among other things. Since you're using PHP, you might want to search for report writers or report generators that have been written in PHP. PostgreSQL doesn't ship with a native report generator.

Comment: Instead of images, could you post some sample data and expected results?  It would be much easier to answer your question that way.